# How to stop helm deleting vertical split when opening helm buffer?

Tags: helm, buffers, window

I have `(setq helm-always-two-windows t)`. When invoking a helm buffer i.e `helm-find-files` or `helm-mini` with 2 vertical splits helm deletes the other window in preperation to perform a possible persistent action in the currently selected window.

Is there any way to stop helm deleting the other window and preserve the 2 vertical splits when the helm buffer is opened?

ido-mode along with ido-vertical-mode seems to have the exact behaviour I'm after with vertical splits as it has no need to accommodate a persistent action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is part of docstring of the user option `helm-always-two-windows`:

> When non--nil helm will use two windows in this frame.
>   That is one window to display ‘helm-buffer’ and one to display
>   ‘helm-current-buffer’.

So `(setq helm-always-two-windows t)` won't do what you want.

---

Here is a work-around by using [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle)

```el
(setq helm-display-function #'pop-to-buffer)

(setq shackle-rules '(("\\`\\*helm.*?\\*\\'" :regexp t :align t :ratio 0.46)))
(shackle-mode)
```

Note, the only downside that I know is helm's full-frame won't work anymore, e.g., `helm-top` won't use full-frame.